# .Net Framework 4.6.1 WebApi, Attribute routing and default routing not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, jwt, authorize-attribute, .net-4.6.1

I appreciate any help on this. I'm currently working on a project where we basically have to convert an older .Net Framework MVC application into an API being utilized by a React front end. We were able to basically convert an MVC controller into an API controller without using ApiController. Now we realized we need to secure the API, and have decided to implement a JWT.

I was able to implement the JWT token creation, and I have that working in my Account Controller which is returning the JWT. The problem I ran into was that I then wanted to implement Authorization on certain endpoints, but had issues with it working on the existing controllers. The documentation at https://github.com/DavidParks8/Owin-Authorization/wiki/Claims-Based-Authorization stated that I should be able to use the authorization on either type of controller, so I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

I thought maybe it was because I was using Controller as opposed to ApiController, so I set up a test controller and created some basic endpoints based on a JWT tutorial I was following. The problem is that when I am attempting to test those endpoints they are not being hit at all and I'm getting a 404.

Here is my configuration:

```
        {
            string secretKey = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SecretKey"];
            SymmetricSecurityKey _signingKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(secretKey));

            // Configure the db context, user manager and signin manager to use a single instance per request
            app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);


            //Enable JWT Authentication:

            app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(
                new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
                    TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                    {
                        ValidateIssuer = true,
                        ValidateAudience = true,
                        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                        ValidIssuer = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Audience"],  
                        ValidAudience = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Audience"],
                        IssuerSigningKey = _signingKey,
                        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero,
                        ValidateLifetime = true,
                        RequireExpirationTime = false
                    },
                    
                });
            //AuthorizationOptions options = new AuthorizationOptions();
            app.UseAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("Principal", policy => policy.RequireClaim(Constants.JwtClaimIdentifiers.Rol, "Principal"));
                options.AddPolicy("Employee", policy => policy.RequireClaim(Constants.JwtClaimIdentifiers.Rol, Constants.JwtClaims.Employee));
                options.AddPolicy("Warranty", policy => policy.RequireClaim(Constants.JwtClaimIdentifiers.Rol, Constants.JwtClaims.Principal));
                options.AddPolicy("Admin", policy => policy.RequireClaim(Constants.JwtClaimIdentifiers.Rol, Constants.JwtClaims.Principal));
            });
```

This was based on documentation and tutorials I went over, and is using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Authorization and Microsoft.Owin.Security.Jwt

Here is my WebApiConfig:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services
            // Configure Web API to use only bearer token authentication.
            config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
            config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));
            var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
            json.SupportedMediaTypes
                .Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
            json.SerializerSettings.DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat;
            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.EnableCors();

            //config.MessageHandlers.Add(new TokenValidationHandler());

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            //var jsonpFormatter = new JsonpMediaTypeFormatter(config.Formatters.JsonFormatter);
            //config.Formatters.Insert(0, jsonpFormatter);
        }
    }
```

And here is my test controller:

```
public class TestController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [Route("GetToken")]
        public Object GetToken()
        {
            string key = "my_secret_key_12345"; //Secret key which will be used later during validation    
            var issuer = "example.com";  //normally this will be your site URL    

            var securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key));
            var credentials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

            //Create a List of Claims, Keep claims name short    
            var permClaims = new List<Claim>();
            permClaims.Add(new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()));
            permClaims.Add(new Claim("valid", "1"));
            permClaims.Add(new Claim("userid", "1"));
            permClaims.Add(new Claim("name", "bilal"));

            //Create Security Token object by giving required parameters    
            var token = new JwtSecurityToken(issuer, //Issuer    
                issuer,  //Audience    
                permClaims,
                expires: DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),
                signingCredentials: credentials);
            var jwtToken = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
            return new { data = jwtToken };
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [Route("GetName1")]
        public string GetName1()
        {
            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                var identity = User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
                if (identity != null)
                {
                    IEnumerable<Claim> claims = identity.Claims;
                }
                return "Valid";
            }
            else
            {
                return "Invalid";
            }
        }


        [HttpPost]
        [Route("GetName2")]
        public Object GetName2()
        {
            if (User.Identity is ClaimsIdentity identity)
            {
                IEnumerable<Claim> claims = identity.Claims;
                var name = claims.Where(p => p.Type == "name").FirstOrDefault()?.Value;
                return new
                {
                    data = name
                };

            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

So when I try to call http://localhost:29523/api/Test/GetToken, I'm getting the 404 error. I'm using Postman, and I can hit endpoints in another controller, but it's an MVC controller, and it's not following API routing. For example, /registration/GetAccountManagementInfo?userGuid=a182235e-c71d-47a5-b31d-f556288b3c3f works and I'm able to get the response.

To summarize, the reason I'm testing with this ApiController is because if I can make this work, and get the Authorization to work on ApiController then I'm going to convert my "registration" controller into an ApiController, since I have had trouble getting that controller to use the authorization middleware that I set up.

Anyway, I'm sure there is other information I could provide, but I'm at my wits end at this point trying to figure out how to troubleshoot this further.

I know that it's trying to reach the controller because if I add a constructor it's hitting the breakpoint at the constructor, but just can't find the route from there. I don't see what's wrong with my setup but I feel like there have to be some wires crossed somewhere with this set up. This is an application I inherited. I wish I could start in a fresh project with .Net core but we just don't have the time for that right now.

Anyways, sorry for the length of this post, I'm really hoping someone can give me some direction. I've looked through countless other posts getting to this point and I haven't found anything that has helped me figure this out so far.

Comment: Why you mixed net 4 with net core? What are you really using?

Comment: You should make sure it's a pure 404 on the URI you're actually trying to reach. Because there is a well-known redirect problem with Identity, where what you see is actually a 302 redirect first to an address that doesn't exist (in some scenarios).

Comment: It's targeted at .Net 4.6.1, the app.UseAuthorization comes from a nuget package where the Authorize stuff was backported to .net 4
https://github.com/DavidParks8/Owin-Authorization

Comment: Also, what was the specific issue you experienced with authorization on the non-api controller endpoints? I think you don't mention that.

Comment: Leaky, that's interesting, if you have any links regarding that it would be appreciated. I'm going to do some searching based on what you said.

Comment: Leaky, the issue was that I configured everything per documentation and other resources and when I added the attribute to the endpoints in the MVC controller it was just ignoring it and allowing access to the endpoint even without the authorization header in the request

Comment: Well, links not really. :) But it's very easy to explain. If you use Identity via `AddIdentity()` (or the other confusing extension methods), it can override your authentication scheme/settings. So you always should place `AddAuthentication` after `AddIdentity` (or at least when you want to use a custom auth config).

Comment: No, doesn't look like Identity is configured that way. Identity is configured before the auth stuff as far as I can tell

Comment: Well, at least that makes it a more interesting problem. :) Oh no, I realized I was myopic again, and this has nothing to do with Asp.Net Core. So I can't help, because I haven't worked with the old system for years.

Comment: Well, I just stepped through, and it is hitting identity stuff but the exception specifically specifies that it couldn't find that route, so I think it's basically just initializing the usermanager and identitymanger before going to the controller

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229844/discussion-between-cabshere-and-leaky).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this? It doesn't seem you have to put `Test` in address. In your case it should be without "Test".

```
http://localhost:29523/api/GetToken
```